# Find recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find recurrence relation for strings of length n using 7 letter alphabet. Each character in the string is the same as previous one or the following one.

The start is easy - first two characters in the sequence will have to be the same. If third character is not the same then we basically have $a_{n-2}$ on our hands.

I have a problem conceptualizing what happens if the third character is the same as previous two.

Looking at first few numbers of sequence isn't insightful for me either

$a_0 = 1$ $a_1=0$ $a_2=7$ $a_3=7$ $a_4=7^2$ $a_5=2*7^2$ $a_6=7^3+7^2-7$

Comment: I'm wondering about the square term in your $a_6$. Strings of length 6 with two different letters can be composed as aaabbb or aaaabb or aabbbb. Do you count these strings as separate ones? Then there are $3 \times 7 *6$ many options for  strings of length 6 with two different letters.

Comment: I'm not sure of $a_5$ either.  Seems to me there are three patterns:  $AABBB$ ($42$ instances), $AAABB$ (also $42$ instances) , and $AAAAA$ ($7$ instances). Hence $91$.

Comment: I've posted a solution below which does not match your numbers (so it might be incorrect).  I note that it does give $91$ for $a_5$ so my interpretation appears to be consistent, at least.

Comment: It seems I didn't count them correctly. Thanks for fixing my mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  my numbers are not matching yours, so possibly what follows contains a blunder.

Let $A_n$ be the number of "good" strings of length $n$.

Let $B_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ wherein the last character does not match its predecessor but which are otherwise good. And let $T_n=A_n+B_n$.

We note the initial conditions $A_0=1,\;A_1=0,\;B_0=0,\;B_1=7$

Then $$n≥2\implies A_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}=T_{n-1}$$ $$n≥2 \implies B_{n}=6\times A_{n-1}=6T_{n-2}$$  It follows that, for $n≥3$, $T_n$ satisfies the linear recursion: $$T_n=T_{n-1}+6T_{n-2}$$  Can you finish from here?

For comparison:  I get $$\{A_n\}=\{1,0,7,7,49,91,385,931,3241,8827,\cdots\}$$

Also worth noting:  For $n≥3$ we can solve the linear recursion (using the values previously computed to supply initial conditions for $T_3,\;T_4$).  We get $$n≥3\implies A_{n+1}=T_n=\frac 75 \times (3^n-(-2)^n)$$

Comment: Shoudn't $a_6$ be 343? By repeating your reasoning in a comment above, there are these patterns: $AABBCC$ (210 instances), $AABBBB$ (42), $AAABBB$ (42), $AAAABB$ (42), $AAAAAA$ (7). Where do the other 42 instances come from?

Comment: Type $AABBCC$ can have any of the seven for $A$, any of the other six for $B$ can $C$ can be anything besides $B$, so six again.  Hence $7\times 6\times 6=252$.

Comment: Note, though, that $7=T_2\not=T_1+6T_0=0+6\cdot1=6$.

Comment: @BarryCipra  You are correct.  Because of that first $7$ in the $B's$, the recursion on the $T's$ doesn't hold at the start.  I will edit accordingly.

Comment: If you ignore $A_0$ and divide the rest by $7$, you get [OEIS A015441](https://oeis.org/A015441), the generalized Fibonacci numbers. Once you get into the recurrent regime, $A_n$ is also also the number of $7$-colored compositions of into parts of size at least $2$ such that no two adjacent parts have the same color.

Comment: To be honest I have a problem following your reasoning. Would you mind being a bit more explicit? I have a problem with $B_n = 6*A_{n-1}$ If we take a good string and shorten it by one, then adding wrong character to it instead creates invalid string. Why is it useful for us?

Comment: Take a good string in $A_{n-1}$.  Append any of the characters to it except the one it happens to end in and you get a string in $B_n$.  And of course deleting the last character of a string in $B_n$ gives you a string in $A_{n-1}$.  Hence $B_n=6A_{n-1}$.

Comment: To be clear:  the strings in $B_n$ are not good.  They are "almost" good, in that they are good except for the last character.  Your question just concerns $A_n$...but it turns out that thinking about $A_n$ and $B_n$ together clarifies the recursion.